# How to sql query include row number in linq query in c#?

Tags: c#, linq

I'm trying to do the following sql query with linq but I couldn't understand it and it sounds confused.
Can I do it with linq or lambda?Can you help me write this query with linq?

```
int pp=0;
int typesquery=0;
string query;
if
{

   a is change value.
 }
```

I try:

```
   SELECT TOP PERCENT NAME,SURNAME,DEPARTMENTID,DEPARTMENTNAME,ROW_NUMBER() over(PARTITION BY 
    NAME,SURNAME ORDER BY NAME,SURNAME) AS INF_NUMBER 
    FROM PERSON AS S
    GROUP BY NAME,SURNAME,PERSONNUM,DEPARTMENTID,DEPARTMENTTYPE

THİS Linq query

var query= from x in PERSON
           .OrderBy( x => x.NAME, x=>x.SURNAME)
           .SELECT (x=>x.NAME,x=>x.SURNAME,x=>x.DEPARTMENTID,x=>x.DEPARTMENTNAME)
```

but not Couldn't combine batch way.

Comment: .SELECT ((x,i) =>new { index = i, name = x.NAME,surname = x.SURNAME,departmentId = x.DEPARTMENTID, departmentName = x.DEPARTMENTNAME})

Comment: LINQ is a query (that is what the Q is) and not meant for writing.  To write you need a FOR loop.

Comment: how do I use the for loop

Comment: foreach(var q in query)